# Rename File with modified date using batch file

Tags: batch-file

Good day,

I'm likely new in creating batch file. My goal is to copy files from source to Target Folder and rename the file with modified date once they are into the Target Folder. I'm having quit a challenge in getting the modified date. It is showing or renaming the file with the CURRENT DATE and not the Modified Date. Here is my code for your reference:

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
::set tDate=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%
set tDate=%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4%
set source="C:\Source Folder"
set target=%userprofile%\Desktop\backup
for %%i in (%source%\AL*.*) do (
::set myfiledate=%%~ta
copy "%%i" "%target%\%tDate%_%%~nxi"
)
```

I really appreciate your input on this matter

Thanks

Comment: So - you're setting `tdate` from the current date, then scanning the directory and copying the file using `tdate`, so there's no surprise that the target file has the current date as part of its name. It's poor practice to have a `::comment` within a code block - it's a broken label and can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks for input. i'll take of that one regarding the comment. so how can i exctract the modified date and append it on a filename.

Comment: Read the help of `for` (type `for /?` into a commad prompt window), particularly the part eith the `~` modifiers; you will find that there is a way to get the last modification date; note that this returns the date in a locale-dependent manner, just like `%DATE%` and `%TIME%` variables...

Answer (score 0):

```
...
for %%i in (%source%\AL*.*) do (
set myfiledate=%%~ti
ECHO(copy "%%i" "%target%\!myfiledate:~0,2!!myfiledate:~5,2!!myfiledate:~6,4!_%%~nxi"
)
```

I'm assuming you want the date in your new file in the format aabbyyyy, but I'd suggest you use YYYYMMDD for ease of sorting.

I'd also suggest you start by `echo`ing the copy command to ensure it's correct (as shown above) - just remove the `echo(` to actually **do** the copy.

The sequence of the three concatenated date elements `!myfiledate:~x,y!` may need to be changed depending on your settings and requirements. They should extract the year, month and day.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the code and it did copy, but the modified date didnt show on the filename. The Filename when from this to this:

13-03-2017_AL & PP (3) to _AL & PP (3)

Comment: I simply copied your code and removed the `::` comment. The metavariable `%%i` is being used and this must match the metavariable used in the assignment.

Comment: I simply copied your code and removed the `::` comment. The metavariable `%%i` is being used and this must match the metavariable used in the assignment.

Comment: Hi, i ran the code on cmd, and here is the result:
copy "C:\Source Folder\AL & PP (3).pdf" "C:\Users\Shore360\Desktop\backup\01017/ 04:_AL & PP (3).pdf"
copy "C:\Source Folder\AL & PP.pdf" "C:\Users\Shore360\Desktop\backup\01017/ 04:_AL & PP.pdf"
copy "C:\Source Folder\AL (1).pdf" "C:\Users\Shore360\Desktop\backup\01011/ 05:_AL (1).pdf"

Comment: The sequence and layout of the date string I extracted from your code. There's no universal layout - it can be changed to user-requirements. In the same way as you have constructed `tdate` from elements of the `%date%` string, so in the same way, `mydate` elements are extracted. From the results you posted in comments (given that I also doubled the first element - typo) then your first file has `mydate`= ????7/?01? 04:?? so I'll conclude that it's actually ??/07/201? 04:?? Now which are month and which day isn't clear - the formula is offset (counting from 0),length.

Comment: so how can i modify my codes to have the output based on my requirements?

Comment: `ECHO(copy "%%i" "%target%\!myfiledate:~0,2!!myfiledate:~5,2!!myfiledate:~6,4!_%%~nxi"
)` as I posted (it's been edited) or possibly `ECHO(copy "%%i" "%target%\!myfiledate:~5,2!!myfiledate:~0,2!!myfiledate:~6,4!_%%~nxi"
)` or `ECHO(copy "%%i" "%target%\!myfiledate:~6,4!!myfiledate:~5,2!!myfiledate:~0,2!_%%~nxi"
)` or `ECHO(copy "%%i" "%target%\!myfiledate:~6,4!!myfiledate:~0,2!!myfiledate:~5,2!_%%~nxi"
)` - take your choice.

Comment: I modify the code:

@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set source="C:\Source Folder"
set target=%userprofile%\Desktop\backup
for %%i in (%source%\AL*.*) do (
set myfiledate=%%~ti
copy "%%i" "%target%\!myfiledate:~10,4!!myfiledate:~4,2!!myfiledate:~7,2!_%%~nxi"
)

Error: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."